# minimum weight connected subset T of edges algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Consider the problem of finding a minimum weight connected subset T of edges
from a weighted connected graph G. The weight of T is the sum of all the edge
weights in T.
(a) Why is this problem not just the minimum spanning tree problem? Hint: think
negative weight edges.
(b) Give an efficient algorithm to compute the minimum weight connected subset
T.

(c) from Sciena Manual

(a) spanning tree minimizes summary tree weight, but `minimum weight connected subset` - every pair path weight, so we can reuse same negative edges to reduce each pair path?

(b) decision on the forehead: run dijkstra's alg n times, tracking previous pairs shortest paths. Seems not the best one, other idea - sort all edges and going from the largest - try to remove each and check connectivity...

Comment: What's your question?  We're not going to do your homework for you!

Comment: I don't thinking finding shortest paths will work. The selected edges don't necessarily have to form a simple path between two nodes. For example: `1 - 2 (-1); 2 - 3 (-2); 2 - 4 (-4)`: you'd select all the edges, but they don't form a path. So I don't think this involves paths, at least not in a really obvious way.

Comment: I could not parse your answer for (a). Could you clarify?

Answer (score 0):

For part A:

Consider K3 (triangle) with each edge having a weight of -1.

What is the MST and what is the Minimum-weight connected subset?

Comment: I think what you have given is a bad example. In your example, MST is the same as Minimum_Weight Connected subset